# Fumbled my phone and somehow accidentally disabled a feature I depend on: Voice Recorder stays on-screen when screen is locked

Tags: applications, settings, lock-screens, motorola, android-one

I fumbled my phone just now and somehow accidentally disabled a feature I depend on, which has worked fine for years: Voice Recorder stays on-screen when screen is locked.

Now the app is unusable while the screen is locked (i.e.: it behaves just like every other app).

I'm trying to figure out what I checked or unchecked in my haphazard attempt to snatch my phone before it hit the ground.

I've looked thru the settings, but the closest thing I've found is "display over other apps", which doesn't seem to do what I want.

Android 10 running on a Motorola One Action.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Could you [edit] and add some more details, like what is the device model, Android version, and which voice recorder app?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, forgot to add that info. It's in there now.